# Echo all links in a HTML page PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

How would I echo all links from an HTML page use DOMDocument?
My current code

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$output = new DOMDocument;
$links = $dom ->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link)
{
     $output->importNode($link);
}
echo $output -> saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$output = new DOMDocument;
$output->formatOutput = true;
$links = $dom ->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link){
    $node = $output->importNode($link, true);
    $output->appendChild($node);
}
echo $output -> saveHTML();
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.